# What are the Hardware requirement for Debian Linux Kernel 3.16 for PPC architecture?

Tags: linux, debian, embedded, powerpc

We have an Embedded System which is running on Debian Linux Kernel 2.6-2.6 [PowerPC Architecture]. Would like to upgrade the Kernel to 3.16.

What are Hardware Requirements?

Comment: You're asking for something that is not a question, your asking for a whole procedure to do something. This is not really how this site works. Also if you want some help, you should maybe add  a bit more information like the brand of your computer your cpu model....

Answer (score 1):

Is this a vanilla upstream (or Debian) kernel source? Or could it be modified with patches for your specific hardware? If you don't have details, you might want to check `/proc/version` to for clues on where the kernel came from.

So, assuming it's a vanilla upstream kernel:

We try not to break support for platforms between kernel versions, but that does depend on testing (and we don't have access to every ppc platform, so a lot of this is community-driven). There isn't a specific set of "hardware requirements"; if your platform booted on 2.6, then it *should* also boot with later kernels. If not, then do get in touch with the community at `linuxppc-dev@lists.ozlabs.org` for help with debugging.

If you're after documentation, that may depend on what sort of info you're after. There's the documentation in the kernel source tree, under [`Documentation/powerpc/`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/Documentation/powerpc), and there's also a little info at https://github.com/linuxppc/linux/wiki .